# How to filter IIS log in Azure before transfer to storage?

Tags: iis, azure

First I want to filter IIS log, In local machine, I can edit my `applicationHost.config` file like this:

```
 <logFile logExtFileFlags="Date, Time, ClientIP, UserName, ServerIP, Method, UriStem, UriQuery, HttpStatus, Win32Status, BytesSent, TimeTaken, ServerPort, UserAgent, Referer, ProtocolVersion, Host, HttpSubStatus" />
```

But in Azure how could I do that?

Second I use

```
config.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

to transfer, I wonder to know could I edit this file first(delete some un-useful log ), then transfer to blob?
Any answer will be appreciated.
Thanks

Update:
Use role startup script can edit applicationHost.config, that will help me full control the IIS.

Comment: Are you asking how to filter the log fields? Why not just log the fields you are interested in seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check the below link:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriharsha/archive/2012/10/26/how-to-transfer-iis-logs-to-storage-account-in-a-custom-format.aspx

Comment: Please include the main points of the link in your answer so if the link breaks your answer still stays helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot edit the file before transferring the log to Azure Blob storage - the [transfer process is baked into WAD](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/#step3).

Your best bet is to use an [Azure role startup script](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/17/using-startup-task-in-windows-azure-detailed-summary.aspx) to pick the proper fields you want IIS to log or filter the log after you've downloaded it locally from Azure Blob storage.

> %windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:sites -siteDefaults.logfile.logExtFileFlags:Date,Time,ClientIP,UserName,SiteName,ComputerName,ServerIP,Method,UriStem

Comment: Thanks very much, I will take a look at it and give your feedback later~

Comment: Good find - using `ServerManager` is another approach - however since it relies on the **site name** from `ServiceDefinition.csdef` it could be a bit fragile of an approach if your site name changes. Modifying the IIS **site defaults** is more stable since it isn't dependent upon the site name.